Unexpected behaviour with background-image positioning
I'm trying to build a timeline using CSS background properties, with colors alternating every hour.
That initial part works fine, with the following css properties (for example for a timeline representing 16h):
.timeline {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #eee, #eee 50%, #aaa 50%, #aaa);
  background-size: 12.5% 12.5%;
}

Now I'm trying to offset the timeline by a number of minutes, so that for example the background starts halfway through a color if the timeline is offset by 30 minutes.
My initial assumption is that if since each section of the background represents 2h and is 12.5% wide, then offsetting by 30 minutes should be 25% of 12.5% => 3.125%.
.offset-half {
  background-position-x: 3.125%;
}

However, does not neatly offset things by half, so something must be off with my understanding of how background-position-x, but I can't figure it out.


.timeline {
  width            : 100%;
  height           : 50px;
  background-image : linear-gradient(to right, #eee, #eee 50%, #aaa 50%, #aaa);
  background-size  : 12.5% 12.5%;
  }
.offset-half {
  background-position-x : 3.125%;
  }
<div class="timeline offset-half"></div>



Goal is to get the background to start exactly halfway through the dark gray section
Since dark grey + light grey is 12.5% wide, I assume that just the dark grey is 6.25%
and half of that is 3.125%, but that doesn't work, the background starts way past the mid point.
Any help in understanding where I go wrong here would be greatly appreciated!

why did you make a codepen? SO. snippet are devil ?

using percentage with background is not as simple as that. Read the duplicate to understand how they work (a bit long but worth it)
